# Skype Ap2Ap on Android?

Tags: android, skype

Is it possible to use Skype Ap2Ap on Android (or iOS), and if so how?

([Ap2Ap](http://blogs.skype.com/2005/12/07/ap2ap-sample/#fbid=owIWoQbj3QJ) is a feature of the Skype API that lets you open a stream and send arbitrary data to anybody on you contact list. Both parties just need to be logged in and to know the application name, and skype does all the hard work like finding the other's IP, bypassing routers, etc.. The feature has been around for a bit and doesn't seem to be used much, but works fine and is available on Windows, Linux, and OS X.)

Comment: That article was published in 07/12/2005. You sure that library is actually available?

Comment: @peter_budo Yes, there's a very nice python API called [Skype4Py](http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/30/resurrecting-skype4py/) that has been updated just a couple of days ago. Check out the ap2ap example [client](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/blob/master/examples/app2app_client.py) and [server](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/blob/master/examples/app2app_server.py), they work just fine. The reason I linked the old article is that there is almost no offical documentation about ap2ap.